# How can I draw a circle in OpenGL Core 3.3 with orthographic projection?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm a complete beginner to OpenGL programming and am trying to follow the Breakout tutorial at [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Collisions/Ball) but would like to draw the ball as an actual circle, instead of using a textured quad like Joey suggests. However, every result that Google throws back at me for "draw circle opengl 3.3" or similar phrases seems to be at least a few years old, and using even-older-than-that versions of the API :-(

The closest thing that I've found is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583368/how-to-draw-multiple-objects-in-opengl-using-multiple-vao-and-vbo), but of course the OP just **had** to use a custom `VertexFormat` object to abstract some of the details, without sharing his/her implementation of such! Just my luck! :P

There's also [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDCSKlFqpaU) that uses a seemingly-older version of the API, but copying the code verbatim (except for the last few lines which is where the code looks old) still got me nowhere.

My version of [`SpriteRenderer::initRenderData()`](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Rendering-Sprites) from the tutorial:

```
void SpriteRenderer::initRenderData() {
    GLuint vbo;

    auto attribSize = 0;
    GLfloat* vertices = nullptr;

    // Determine whether this sprite is a circle or
    // quad and setup the vertices array accordingly
    if (!this->isCircle) {
        attribSize = 4;
        vertices = new GLfloat[24] {...}   // works for rendering quads
    } else {
        // This code is adapted from the YouTube tutorial that I linked
        // above and is where things go pear-shaped for me...or at least
        // **not** circle-shaped :P
        attribSize = 3;

        GLfloat x = 0.0f;
        GLfloat y = 0.0f;
        GLfloat z = 0.0f;
        GLfloat r = 100.0f;

        GLint numSides = 6;
        GLint numVertices = numSides + 2;

        GLfloat* xCoords = new GLfloat[numVertices];
        GLfloat* yCoords = new GLfloat[numVertices];
        GLfloat* zCoords = new GLfloat[numVertices];

        xCoords[0] = x;
        yCoords[0] = y;
        zCoords[0] = z;

        for (auto i = 1; i < numVertices; i++) {
            xCoords[i] = x + (r * cos(i * (M_PI * 2.0f) / numSides));
            yCoords[i] = y + (r * sin(i * (M_PI * 2.0f) / numSides));
            zCoords[i] = z;
        }

        vertices = new GLfloat[numVertices * 3];
        for (auto i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            vertices[i * 3] = xCoords[i];
            vertices[i * 3 + 1] = yCoords[i];
            vertices[i * 3 + 2] = zCoords[i];
        }
    }

    // This is where I go back to the learnopengl.com code. Once
    // again, the following works for quads but not circles!
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(
        GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, attribSize, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
        attribSize * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And here's the [`SpriteRenderer::DrawSprite()`](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Rendering-Sprites) method (the only difference from the original being lines 24 - 28):

```
void SpriteRenderer::Draw(vec2 position, vec2 size, GLfloat rotation, vec3 colour) {
    // Prepare transformations
    shader.Use();

    auto model = mat4(1.0f);
    model = translate(model, vec3(position, 0.0f));

    model = translate(model, vec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));   // Move origin of rotation to center
    model = rotate(model, rotation, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));              // Rotate quad
    model = translate(model, vec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f)); // Move origin back

    model = scale(model, vec3(size, 1.0f)); // Lastly, scale

    shader.SetMatrix4("model", model);

    // Render textured quad
    shader.SetVector3f("spriteColour", colour);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture.Bind();

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    if (!isCircular) {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    } else {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 24);  // also tried "12" and "8" for the last param, to no avail
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And finally, the shaders (different to the ones used for quads):

```
// Vertex shader
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * model *
        vec4(position.xyz, 1.0f);
}

// Fragment shader
#version 330 core

out vec4 colour;

uniform vec3 spriteColour;

void main() {    
    colour = vec4(spriteColour, 1.0);
}
```

P.S. I know I could just use a quad but I'm trying to learn how to draw **all** primitives in OpenGL, not just quads and triangles (thanks anyway Joey)!

P.P.S I just realised that the learnopengl.com site has a whole section devoted to debugging OpenGL apps, so I set that up but to no avail :-( I don't think the error handling is supported by my driver (Intel UHD Graphics 620 latest driver) since the `GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT` was not set after following the instructions:

> Requesting a debug context in GLFW is surprisingly easy as all we have to do is pass a hint to GLFW that we'd like to have a debug output context. We have to do this before we call glfwCreateWindow:
>
> glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
>
> Once we initialize GLFW we should have a debug context if we're using OpenGL version 4.3 or higher, or else we have to take our chances and hope the system is still able to request a debug context. Otherwise we have to request debug output using its OpenGL extension(s).
>
> To check if we successfully initialized a debug context we can query OpenGL:
>
> GLint flags; glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &flags);
>
> if (flags & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT) {
>       // initialize debug output 
>   }

That `if` statement is never entered into!

Comment: What's the result you get?

Comment: The last parameter of [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) has to be the number of vertices. Waht do you mean by *"how to draw all primitives"*? OpenGL [Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) are points, lines and triangles.

Comment: Do you ever set the uniform `projection`, after the program is installed (by `shader.Use();`)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments peeps! :-) @ybungalobill I get most of my scene rendered correctly, except the circles which don't appear at all. @Rabbid76 Sorry I thought "primitives" meant "basic 2D shapes". Guess I need to read a LOT more documentation lol :P And yes, I set the projection matrix in my game's setup function, like so : `circleShader.Use().SetMatrix4("projection", ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(this->Width), static_cast<GLfloat>(this->Height), 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f));`.

Comment: [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mykola's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858753/drawing-a-circle-using-opengl-c) I have gotten half-way there:

```
numVertices = 43;
vertices = new GLfloat[numVertices];

auto i = 2;
auto x = 0.0f,
     y = x,
     z = x,
     r = 0.3f;

auto numSides = 21;
auto TWO_PI = 2.0f * M_PI;
auto increment = TWO_PI / numSides;

for (auto angle = 0.0f; angle <= TWO_PI; angle += increment) {
    vertices[i++] = r * cos(angle) + x;
    vertices[i++] = r * sin(angle) + y;
}
```

Which gives me [image: this].

Two questions I still have:

1. Why is there an extra line going from the centre to the right side and how can I fix it?
2. According to [@user1118321's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444450/drawing-circle-with-opengl#comment34136534_22444511) on a related SO answer, I should be able to prepend another vertex to the array at (0, 0) and use `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` instead of `GL_LINE_LOOP`
   to get a coloured circle. But this results in no output for me :-( Why?